# MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, express, database-connection

when i run this code and add a product to the database using thunder client it produces this error
i also whitelisted my ip and also added 0.0.0.0/0 to the mongodb atlas

```
PS D:\E - Commerce\backend> node index.js
Server Running on Port 4000
D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186
          const err = new MongooseError(message);
                      ^

MongooseError: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:186:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)

Node.js v20.11.0
PS D:\E - Commerce\backend>
```

This is my index.js file

```
const port = 4000;
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const multer = require("multer");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const { time } = require("console");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

// DataBase connection with MangoDB
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://Tamil:password2488@cluster0.5nh2chn.mongodb.net/e-commerce"
);

// API Creation

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Express App is Running");
});

// Image Storage Engine

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./upload/images",
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// Creating upload Endpoints for images

app.use("/images", express.static("upload/images"));

app.post("/upload", upload.single("product"), (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    success: 1,
    image_url: `http://localhost:${port}/images/${req.file.filename}`,
  });
});

// Schema for Creating Products

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", {
  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  new_price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  old_price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  avilable: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
});

app.post("/addproduct", async (req, res) => {
  let products = await Product.find({});
  let id;
  if (products.length > 0) {
    let last_product_array = products.slice(-1);
    let last_product = last_product_array[0];
    id = last_product.id + 1;
  } else {
    id = 1;
  }
  const product = new Product({
    id: id,
    name: req.body.name,
    image: req.body.image,
    category: req.body.category,
    new_price: req.body.new_price,
    old_price: req.body.old_price,
  });
  console.log(product);
  await product.save();
  console.log("Saved");
  res.json({
    success: true,
    name: req.body.name,
  });
});

// Creating API for deleting Products

app.post("/removeproduct", async (req, res) => {
  await Product.findOneAndDelete({ id: req.body.id });
  console.log("Removed");
  res.json({
    success: true,
    name: req.body.name,
  });
});

// Creating API for getting all products

app.get("/allproducts", async (req, res) => {
  let products = await Product.find({});
  console.log("All Products Fetched");
  res.send(products);
});

app.listen(port, (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    console.log("Server Running on Port " + port);
  } else {
    console.log("Error :" + error);
  }
});
```

using post method i added the product

http://localhost:4000/addproduct/

and JSON content is
{
"name": "Product 40",
"old_price": 50,
"new_price": 40,
"category": "kid",
"image": "http://localhost:4000/images/product_1707626365144.png"
}
and in thunder client, in response tab it shows
Status: ERROR
Size: 0 B
Time: 0 ms
Connection was forcibly closed by a peer.
after running 10s.

also without adding the product or any other operations, the server stops running after 30s of time and produces this error.

```
PS D:\E - Commerce\backend> node index.js
Server Running on Port 4000
D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:829
    err = new ServerSelectionError();
          ^

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
    at _handleConnectionErrors (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:829:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:804:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-00.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-00.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1264626,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.93.17.249:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.93.17.249:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '34.93.17.249',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-01.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-01.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1264625,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.93.216.164:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 34.93.216.164:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '34.93.216.164',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      },
      'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-02.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'ac-a3zigto-shard-00-02.5nh2chn.mongodb.net:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 1264655,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.244.56.252:27017
            at connectionFailureError (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (D:\E - Commerce\backend\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
          [cause]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 35.244.56.252:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1595:16) {
            errno: -4039,
            code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '35.244.56.252',
            port: 27017
          }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-7gjnfs-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Node.js v20.11.0
PS D:\E - Commerce\backend>
```

anyone know how to solve this issue